# Microsoft Azure Functions and Node - I'm a Mac user. How do I upload/install Node packages within Azure Portal?

Tags: node.js, macos, azure, azure-functions

I'm developing a Node application/Azure Function app in Microsoft Azure and am having a hell of a time figuring out where and how to install Node packages. I'm on a Mac and have mostly developed the guts of the application in my local development environment. I've pasted the contents of my local JavaScript files into the Azure UI, and that's working out fine, except that I'm not sure of how to install third-party Node modules. Is there an easy way to basically get a command-line view of the project and to somehow thereby install the necessary modules via NPM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed! You can get a console in the portal and do an npm install. See [Node version and Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management).